# I have something in my neck that ruins my prayer will Allah(SWT) forgive me?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

When I prayed the two Fard prayers of Fajr, my neck has been suffering for a while, also when I prayed Zuhr or Asr, and also during the one last rakats of Maghrib and the two last rakats for Isha.

I was wondering whether my prayer is still valid.

Comment: Is it a medical issue? If it is you should consult a doctor to see what it is

Comment: Will Allah still give me the reward for the past prayers and what if I can't contact a doctor?

Comment: What exactly is it with your neck? Is it affecting your speech?

Comment: Each couple of words in this post I ask myself, what do you mean to say and why can't you this and that? To me it is unclear what your question is the question title seems to point at a medical issue the content sounds like waswas. Please edit this blury text and ask a clear concise question with all necessary information. See also [ask].

Comment: No its whenever i pray silent salats like Zuhr,Asr and the the one last rakats for Maghrib and the two last rakats for Isha I make noises.

Comment: Why did I get a -3 please explain so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by ruin you mean you missed prayer then yes it is sin and you should offer missed prayers. But if your mean you offered prayers but they were not looking perfect due to pain or illness then your prayers are offered if you offered to the level best you was capable. In prayer leverage is given on medical basis, you have to offer in any situation to the level best possible. In worst case you can offer prayers with signs and they are accepted by Allah.